# How to avoid truncation of SQL Join result due to UP TO clause?

Tags: sql, join, abap, opensql

I have a join over three tables A,B and C.
The primary key for all three table is PK1 which is the join condition.
On the selection screen there is a parameter to restrict the result in the report.

This parameter is used as the UP TO clause for SQL statement. Due to the join, we could exceed the number of results but because of the UP TO condition, the final result list is truncated. Any ideas how to avoid this?
Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM a
JOIN b
  ON a.pk1 = b.pk1
JOIN C
  ON b.PK1 = c.pk1
WHERE ...
UP TO 250 rows.
```

How do I check in the code if I have missed any result for the PK1?

EDIT1:
1. The selection screen has a feature to restrict the result which is a must requirement. Hence, the complication with the truncation.

Comment: What is an UP TO clause?

Comment: UP TO n rows restricts the result set.https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abapfrom_clause.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@

Comment: If you do not want the result set to be limited to a certain number of records, why did you specify the `UP TO n ROWS` clause in the first place?

Comment: This is a feature from the selection screen and is a requirement. Earlier with all reports was easy to handle as there were no joins. With join you might miss out on few results due to this condition.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. If you want to know if `UP TO` truncated your results, ask for `n+1` results rather than `n`. Display `n` results, but if you actually obtained `n+1`, you know truncation has occurred.

Comment: If it is a feature from the selection screen, why is there a hardcoded value `250` in your code? If this parameter should actually be entered on the selection screen, then enter 0 and there will be no restriction at all as stated in the documentation. `UP TO 0 ROWS` means select all even if it does not explicitly say so.

Comment: It was just an example code, off course it is not hard-coded this way. On rethinking i decided to make one more select from the found result (JOIN_1) so that to make sure if i haven't missed any results. This way I can keep the max. hits selection parameter.